# Extract nested key from string data structure

Tags: ruby

I am using mailgun for sending email. It has api for add “Unsubscribe me” feature. I am using it in my rails app.

Using this command, i get list of all unsubscribed users i.e. entries in unsubscribes table of mailgun.

```
 RestClient.get "https://api:key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0"  "@api.mailgun.net/v2/samples.mailgun.org/unsubscribes"
```

I am storing its output in @unsubscriber. So my controller has:

```
  @unsubscribers = RestClient.get "https://api:key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0"  "@api.mailgun.net/v2/samples.mailgun.org/unsubscribes"
```

When i display the output in view, <%= @unsubscribers %> i get string:

```
{
  "total_count": 1,
  "items": [{
    "created_at": "Sun, 11 Aug 2013 08:07:22 GMT",
    "tag": "*",
    "id": "sdfsdfw12423535456",
    "address": "xyz@abc.com"
  }]
}
```

As I want to delete unsubscribed emails from my database, I want only emails in @unsubscribers. But it contains whole string.

I am not getting how to extract email from above string so that i can have list of emails in @unsubscribers and i can delete them from my app.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: @sawa Yeah, but I am looking only for address, not complete string.

Comment: I have added more explanation to make the question clear. Let me know if any further explanation is required.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access the address of the first subscriber:

```
@unsubscriber['items'].first['address']
```

Safer code:

```
((@unsubscriber['items'] || []).first || {} )['address']
```

If you are trying to collect all the addresses:

```
(@unsubscriber['items'] || []).map{|s| ['address']}
```

Comment: it is giving undefined method `map' for "items":String

Comment: What happens when you try the safer version? This can also happen if `@unsubscriber` is `nil`.

Comment: No. @unsubscriber is not nil. Its output i have written in question. For safer version it is giving nil.

Answer (score -1):

`@unsubscriber` is a hash. `items` is an array of hashes. You need to get the first item using `[0]`. Then you need the `address` value

```
@unsubscriber["items"][0]["address"]
```

Comment: it returns nil. Output of @unsubscriber["items"] is item. Output of @unsubscriber["items"][0] is "i" and output of @unsubscriber["items"][0]["address"] is nil.